# How do I use call forwarding and display an edited caller ID string?

Tags: twilio, forwarding

When using call forwarding, is there a way to show the originating phone number with a `+` appended to it? For example, Sue calls 555.1212 from 555.1414. The call is forwarded to 555.1717. The caller ID at 555.1717 would display +555.1414 or 555.1414+.

Basically something to show that the called is being forwarded and who it is from.

Comment: I don't see any programming question here, or code, or language/operating system tags, or any other meaningful information. Are you sure you're on the right site?

Comment: @KenWhite He's asking questions about how to use a relatively popular API. Seems fair to me.

Comment: @David: When I posted my comment, the only tag was `forwarding`, and there's no indication of any programming related content in the question itself. If it's about `twillo`, the question should ask an actual code related question, or at least some indication that there has been some effort to find an answer before posting here. "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work."

Comment: Apologies, but I was directed here through seeking support directly from Twilio.  I'm looking to something like below.  I apologize if I'm not in the right spot and not being detailed enough.  http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=7075551111&CallerId="+"+"CALLFROM"&

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

I assume your asking about how the caller ID number is displayed on there receivers handset?  If thats the case, unfortunately we don't have any way to control the formatting if the caller ID number.

Its often the case that carriers and handsets will apply their own formatting to the caller ID numbers anyways, so even if we let you append the + its likely the carrier would strip it, or the handset would ignore it.

Devin

Comment: Apologies, but I was directed here through seeking support directly from Twilio.  <br>http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=7075551111&CallerId="+"+"CALLFROM"& <br>

Comment: Please disregard the above.  I struck the return key in error and took to long to finish my edit.  :-/